# get access to the window size xaml DataTemplate WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

So, i have the following xaml at the moment-

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MailTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date}" Width="150"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Subject}" Width="300"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=From.DisplayName}" Width="125"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

It's a template of a ListBox item.
The actual details do not really matter, its just about the Width attribute.
Is there a way to access the window's size in order to set the width? I don't want the Width to be constant, i want the TextBlocks to be able to change sizes if you stretch the window.

Comment: There are other panels besides Grid: UniformGrid, StackPanel, DockPanel, WrapPanel. You can even create your own panel with your custom layout logic by deriving from [Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.panel) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by not setting any fixed widths on the `TextBlock` elements, and use a `Grid` with [star-sizing](https://wpf.2000things.com/2011/10/31/419-how-cell-sizes-are-calculated-when-using-star-sizing/) instead of a `StackPanel` as container. For example like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MailTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="125*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Date}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Subject}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=From.DisplayName}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Odd, i remember answering this. i'll just say it again, thank you so much!